# jQuery: How to distinguish the form being submitted inside the success callback function of $.post call?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
  $(".save_button").click(function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest("div.info_section").find("form");
    url = $form.attr("action");
    $.post(url, $form.serialize(), 
      function() {
        // need to figure out a way to distinguish the form being saved
      }
    );
  });
```

I have three forms (on the same page) that are tied to this function. The success callback function of $.post requires a way to distinguish which form is being submitted. Please advise how I would do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `$form` variable inside the `success` callback:

```
$.post(url, $form.serialize(), function() {
    // $form could be used here to access the form element
    // whose contents was serialized and sent in the AJAX request
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I'll accept this answer once the 10 min restriction elapsed.